# Azure configure backup doesn't see PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-devops, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to configure a backup of the PostgreSQL server using the Azure backup center.

I created Vault, a resource group. But when I am trying to configure backup using Vault and Backup policy it can't see the PostgreSQL database server in the resources.

I appreciate any help in troubleshooting the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmKK0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [**official document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/quick-backup-postgresql-database-portal) troubleshooting the issue:

- Select or [**Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/tutorial-postgresql-backup#create-a-backup-vault) a ***Backup Policy*** that defines the ***backup schedule***.
- **+ Add** and select ***PostgreSQL*** database

[image: Ref1]

**Note:**

The backup service validates the necessary ***[access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-database-postgresql-overview#grant-access-on-the-azure-postgresql-server-and-key-vault-manually)*** to read secret details from the **key vault** and ***connect*** to the ***database***
if ***access permission*** is found missing, it will display an `error message-  role assignment not done`, make sure to check and Re-validate role assignment done or not.

**Reference**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-database-postgresql-overview#grant-access-on-the-azure-postgresql-server-and-key-vault-manually

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-backup-restore

Comment: Hey @Mahir Afandiyev, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot.  [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers "https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers")